# how to call a function based on change event in jquery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Below is my HTML and I want to call a JS function every time my input field's value changes inside "foundation-autocomplete" element

```
<foundation-autocomplete class="coral-Form-field" pickersrc="/mnt/overlay/granite/ui/content/coral/foundation/form/pathfield/picker.html?_charset_=utf-8&amp;path={value}&amp;root=%2fcontent&amp;filter=hierarchyNotFile&amp;selectionCount=single">
   <div class="foundation-autocomplete-inputgroupwrapper">
      <div class="coral-InputGroup" role="presentation">
         <input is="coral-textfield" class="coral3-Textfield coral-InputGroup-input" autocomplete="off" placeholder="" id="coral-id-106" role="combobox" aria-expanded="false" aria-invalid="false" value="/swing">
         <span class="coral-InputGroup-button">
            <button is="coral-button" class="coral3-Button coral3-Button--secondary" size="M" variant="secondary" title="Open Selection Dialog" type="button" aria-label="Open Selection Dialog">
               <coral-icon class="coral3-Icon coral3-Icon--sizeS coral3-Icon--select" icon="select" size="S" autoarialabel="on" role="img" aria-label="select"></coral-icon>
               <coral-button-label></coral-button-label>
            </button>
         </span>
      </div>
   </div>
</foundation-autocomplete>
```

I tried with above code but function call is not happening. Is there any other way ?
`
// Select the  element
const foundationAutocomplete = document.querySelector('foundation-autocomplete');

```
// Create a MutationObserver instance
const observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutationsList, observer) {
    // Call your JavaScript function here when a mutation occurs
    yourFunction();
});

// Define your JavaScript function
function yourFunction() {
    // Your code here
    console.log('foundation-autocomplete value changed.');
}

// Configure the MutationObserver to watch for changes to the subtree and attributes
observer.observe(foundationAutocomplete, { subtree: true, attributes: true });
```

`

Comment: I think you want an event listener, rather than a mutation observer.

Comment: You can just have a `change` event for the input element inside the container. `.coral-Form-field input`

Comment: `$("div.foundation-autocomplete-inputgroupwrapper").on("input", function(){....});`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will run `yourFunction` when the input changes:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#coral-id-106').on('change', () => yourFunction() )
})
```

Here's what that means:

- `$(document).ready(function(){` When the web page finishes loading.
- `$('#coral-id-106').on(` Add an event listener to the element with an id of 'coral-id-106.'
- `'change'` The type of event listener - in this case we want something to happen when the element changes.
- `() =>`  shorthand for `function (){`
- `yourFunction()` - The function you want to get triggered when the element changes.